# How do I load a single entry in Sembast based on it's ID?

Tags: flutter, sembast

I look through [a](https://stefangaller.at/app-development/flutter/sembast-local-data-storage/) [bunch](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/sembast-nosql-database-336a523a1567) of tutorials for [Sembast](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast). The tutorials give examples about how to get all the items of a certain class like Cake but not how to load a specific one based on it's ID:

```
  @override
  Future<List<Cake>> getAllCakes() async {
    final snapshots = await _store.find(_database);
    return snapshots
        .map((snapshot) => Cake.fromMap(snapshot.key, snapshot.value))
        .toList(growable: false);
  }
```

How do I lot a single Cake for a given ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `store.record(key).get(db)`

Assuming your key is an int, this could look like this:

```dart
Future<Cake> getCake(int key) async {
  final snapshot = await _store.record(key).getSnapshot(_database);
  return snapshot != null ? Cake.fromMap(key, snapshot.value) : null;
}
```

More information (yes documentation is not that great) [here](https://github.com/tekartik/sembast.dart/blob/master/sembast/doc/queries.md#get-by-key)